# Count number of images selecting in input

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to use the rails method `[number].times {}` in my controller's `new` function to upload multiple images.  However, I need to determine how many images were selected in input box of the view.  How do I output the number of images selected in the image input and replace `[number]` with that output so as to accurately build the right number of image objects?

Comment: In javascript that would be `files.length`, but I don't really see what this question about a RoR controller has to do with jQuery ?

Comment: how do I send that files.length result to the controller as a variable?

Comment: If the images are sent to the serverside, you should count them there, not in javascript.